# Why are the begin and rbegin iterator types different in spelling?

Tags: c++

```cpp
std::list<std::string> list = {"Milton", "Shakespeare", "Austen"};
auto it_1 = list.begin(); // auto -> std::list<std::string>::iterator 
auto it_2 = list.rbegin(); // auto -> std::reverse_iterator<std::list<std::string>::iterator>
// std::list<std::string>::reverse_iterator it_3 = list.rbegin();
```

Please explain why the iterator type for `begin()` when using `auto` is different from the iterator type for `rbegin()`?

What is the understanding that the `begin()` iterator should have type `std::list<std::string>::iterator` and the `rbegin()` iterator should have type `std::list<std::string>::reverse_iterator`, but VS2022 suggests that `rbegin()`'s iterator type is not what I expected:

[image]

I expected `it_2` to be the following type:

`std::list<std::string>::reverse_iterator`

Please explain what type `it_2` actually hides?

Comment: The types are synonymous. `std::reverse_iterator<std::list::iterator> == std::list::reverse_iterator`. See here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list

Comment: Also note that `std::reverse_iterator` is an iterator *adapter* so it's template type is another iterator, rather than a value type in the `std::list<T>::iterator` case.

Comment: `::iterator` doesn't have to be a class, it can be a typedef too. I don't remember if `::reverse_iterator` must be a typedef for `std::reverse_iterator<...>` or it can be something else.

Comment: `std::cout << typeid(it_1).name() << " " << typeid(it_2).name() << " " << (typeid(it_1) == typeid(it_2) ? "MATCH" : "DIFFER") << "\n";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::list<std::string>::reverse_iterator` is required to be a *typedef* of `std::reverse_iterator<std::list<std::string>::iterator>`. This means that they are simply different names for the same class.

Comment: It is actually required. See https://eel.is/c++draft/list.overview. Also in general per https://eel.is/c++draft/container.rev.reqmts.